# Recursion Example in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

Can anyone help me understand how this program is getting to 8 as its final output, its frying my brain!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int unknown(int x);

int main()
{
  cout << unknown(1);
}

int unknown(int x)
{
    int result, y = 2;

    if (x >= 6)
    return 1;
    else
    {
        result = unknown(x + 2) * y;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Walk through it one step at a time.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @eggo, Or if a debugger seems like a daunting prospect to your fried brain (hey, we've all been there) then add some print statements and think through what gets printed out.

Answer (score 1):

The program execution, after unknown(1) is called is as follows:

unknown(1) : result = unknown(1+2) * 2 = unknown(3) * 2

unknown(3) : result = unknown(3+2) * 2 = unknown(5) * 2

unknown(5) : result = unknown(5+2) * 2 = unknown(7) * 2

unknown(7) : return 1

so if we go from the bottom to the top replacing unknown(x) with its result

unknown(7) = 1

unknown(5) = unknown(7) * 2 = 1 * 2 = 2

unknown(3) = unknown(5) * 2 = 2 * 2 = 4

unknown(1) = unknown(3) * 2 = 4 * 2 = 8

The function return 8.

Comment: okay man this was such a good way of explaining it! I totally got it now, thanks very much!!